# Cleanest way to copy Hibernate entities like POJOs in another project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, retrofit2

I have multi-module Maven project:

1. JPA module (Hibernate implementation) with Annotated Entities.
2. Rest-Service module - have dependency to module 1. and Endpoints serialize JSON using Entities from module 1.
3. Rest-Client module: This library is based on [retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) (this jar library is used in Java-EE web project and Android too) and for deserializing JSON model its needs to have dependency to module 1. too. But here Entities needs to be simple POJOs (without JPA annotations)

I don`t want module 3 to have dependency to module 1 and include all Hibernate jars in RestClient (its not need it).

I don`t want to copy Entities only in module 3 and manually to remove annotations.. It`s hard to change Entities next in two places.

I`m trying with [Maven Dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) to copy Entities only.. but its not clear if its possible to remove annotations with this plugin? and is this the most cleanest way of doing it?

Comment: So basically you want to import the module 1 without declaring a dependency to it. May I ask why it is impractical to have a dependency between module 1 and 3? Because your use case seems to be exactly why this maven architecture exists... Otherwise, I guess you could have a look to OSGi: https://www.osgi.org/developer/architecture/

Comment: Its not practically module 3 to have dependency to module 1 why module 3 will receive like transitive all dependency from module 1 including Hibernate this is the reason that Annotations needs to be removed from Entities. I wants module 3 to be used in Android too it cannot have dependency to Hibernate.

Comment: Then why not using the dependency exclusion of Maven? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: I cannot compile module 3 with Hibernate Annotations in Entity without to have Hibernate like dependency :)

Comment: Are we talking about build time or runtime?

Comment: I can copy Entities only from module 1 with Maven Dependency Plugin but how can I build module 3: `mvn install` will fail if I have Annotations like: javax.persistence.Entity and org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete

Comment: To be honest I don't understand your problem. If you build all jars than you can have dependencies which are needed to compile your code correctly. I you only use JPA1/JPA2 annotations which are only interfaces which is the only needed dependencies whereas Hibernate is an JPA implementation which you can defined as `<scope>provided</scope>`. Furthermore using an JPA implementation in your entities sounds from a design perspective wrong. But I'm not sure I correctly understand your problem.

Comment: @khmarbaise maybe you a thinking in wrong direction :) I think that the cleanest way is to remove this JPA2 annotations from Entity in the RestClient library. If I define JPA hibernate-jpa.jar (package containing JPA annotations) in pom.xml with scope provided I can build RestClient library OK. But plain servlet containers like Tomcat, Jetty or Android don`t have hibernate-jpa.jar and I cannot run Android application using RestClient library. RestClient library is a module library that is intended to run in Java web app and Android too. I cannot have dependency to hibernate-jpa-2.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

After many researches I have add swagger support to my RestService:

https://github.com/zhouhao/swagger-spring-boot-jersey

Rest Client module is generated with [swagger-codegen-maven-plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) for Java and [swagger-codegen-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/thebignet/swagger-codegen-gradle-plugin) for Android Gradle project.
This is my configuration for gradle-plugin:

```
swagger {
    inputSpec = 'http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json'

    outputDir = "${rootDir}/swagger-client"
    lang = 'java'

        additionalProperties = [
                'groupId'           : 'com.orgname',
                'artifactId'        : 'swagger-java-client',
                'artifactVersion'   : '1.0.0',
                'invokerPackage'    : 'com.orgname.client.retrofit2',
                'modelPackage'      : 'com.orgname.client.retrofit2.model',
                'apiPackage'        : 'com.orgname.client.retrofit2.api',
                'library'           : 'retrofit2',
                'useRxJava2'        : 'true',
                'useGzipFeature'    : 'true',
                'serializableModel' : 'true',
                'dateLibrary'       : 'java7',
                'templateDir'       : "src/main/resources/Java/libraries/retrofit2"
        ]
    }
```

Model is generated from RestService and there is not need to have dependency to Hibernate Entities model and I think that this is the cleanest way with minimum human effort.